# How can I authenticate with an OAuth API and share access tokens across GCP servers

Tags: google-cloud-platform

An external API that I need to integrate with uses OAuth to authenticate requests. The access/refresh tokens are only valid for a few minutes and are invalidated when authenticating/refreshing, so only 1 set of tokens can be valid at a time.

The difficulty is that I need access to this API across multiple servers and regions. Because they need to share the same access tokens, I need a way to share the tokens across servers and have a single service update them when they expire.

Is there a GCP tool that can provide a proxy to just handle the authentication flow to this API. Or what would the best architecture be to handle this?

I’ve thought about manually storing the tokens in memory store or secret manager. I’d still need to create a service+queue+cron to refresh/authenticate. And my servers would need manual logic to retry on unauthenticated requests. This seems excessively complicated.

I’ve explored Workforce Identity Federation but that helps external servers access GCP hosted services. I need my GCP servers to access an external third party API.

Thanks!!

Comment: Store the tokens as a JSON file in Cloud Storage.

Comment: Storage isn’t the problem but thanks for the tip @JohnHanley

Comment: Your post said `I need a way to share the tokens across servers`.

Comment: Yes. I then explained how simply storing them in a shared location creates a lot of complexity, and merely “saving” the tokens isnt nearly enough.